# error handling in Vb script

Tags: vbscript

I have a Vb script which calls a bat file.the bat file contans logic to send email.i run the bat file using objShell.run.when i give an invalid email server name in the bat file.the email is not sent.But objShell.run always returns a 0.How to do exception handling in this case.please help

Comment: do you set the process exit code in the batch file?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `objShell.run` method it is running a separately process and do not care about the current process you are running. I would look at the `ProcessStartInfo`. I think you can redirect the input/output/error stream from the `ProcessStartInfo`. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/80ea9d75-d808-481b-bc1b-b3e56716119c/) are some link about it

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use CDO to send your email right from the VBScript.  Otherwise, error handling in Batch is extremely difficult and you will have to resort to exit codes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send without installation then try the second method. you have to initialize the objects. In that example i remove h in the link because i can't post links

```
CDO.MESSAGE

'Script to send an email through QTP nice one Set oMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

'==This section provides the configuration information for the remote SMTP server. '==Normally you will only change the server name or IP. oMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _ ("ttp://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2

'Name or IP of Remote SMTP Server oMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _ ("ttp://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") =""

'Server port (typically 25) oMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _ ("ttp://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25

oMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update oMessage.Subject = "Test Mail" oMessage.Sender = "" oMessage.To ="" 'oMessage.CC = "" 'oMessage.BCC = "" oMessage.TextBody = "Test Mail from QTP"&vbcrlf&"Regards,"&vbcrlf&"Test" oMessage.Send

Set oMessage = Nothing
```